# Continuously train MATLAB ANN, i.e. online training?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I would like to ask for ideas what options there is for training a MATLAB ANN (artificial neural network) continuously, i.e. not having a pre-prepared training set? The idea is to have an "online" data stream thus, when first creating the network it's completely untrained but as samples flow in the ANN is trained and converges.

The ANN will be used to classify a set of values and the implementation would visualize how the training of the ANN gets improved as samples flows through the system. I.e. each sample is used for training and then also evaluated by the ANN and the response is visualized.

The effect that I expect is that for the very first samples the response of the ANN will be more or less random but as the training progress the accuracy improves.

Any ideas are most welcome.

Regards, Ola

Comment: Rather than use a sample for training and then also for evaluation, better to divide up samples as they come in. So the first "x" are for training only, thereafter every "nth" one is used to evaluate rather than train.

Comment: Hi Vicky, thanks for your answer. I realize that I was a bit unclear; what I will actually do is to classify an item and then train the ANN with it. Thus, I expect the first classifications to be random and then better and better. The main idea is here not to divide samples, rather jump into a continuous stream of data and use every samples for training. I know how to use train() for the normal case with a training set but I'm not sure of the best way in this case, where do not actually have a training set but continually training the ANN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB you can use the `adapt` function instead of `train`. You can do this incrementally (change weights every time you get a new piece of information) or you can do it every N-samples, batch-style.

[This document](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/training-styles-adapt-and-train.html) gives an in-depth run-down on the different styles of training from the perspective of a time-series problem.

I'd really think about what you're trying to do here, because adaptive learning strategies can be difficult. I found that they like to flail all over compared to their batch counterparts. This was especially true in my case where I work with very noisy signals.

Are you sure that you need adaptive learning? You can't periodically re-train your NN? Or build one that generalizes well enough?

Comment: Thanks, seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. It's actually for educational purpose, i.e. to visualize how the ANN improves with training. For production ANNs I agree that batch is the preferred option.