# Normalize/denormalize and testing & validate ANN matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to design neural network in Matlab,
I see in many source that the data that used with training neural network
better to be normalize, use `[pn,ps] = mapstd(Input)` to normalize the input and target,
then I train the network, last thing i test the network by `a=sim(net,pn)`;
my problem is:

how to convert the result to normal result?

last thing, is there any way to train the network with new data to increase the performance?
i mean train with more data where the weighing change slightly to increase the old performance
it is clear that normalize is mean by this function `[pn,ps] = mapstd(Input)`
all value will be in range of -1 to 1 as i think, the sim of neural network will be normalize result while i have to convert it again to the original range how?

Comment: i didnt know how they are thinking who vote in negative!!

Comment: The negative votes are because your question is too vague and its pretty badly and unclearly explained. You should follow SO rules ig you want some help! give some code, how what is going wrong with it and what have you tried.  As far as I know you can retune your NN but I dont know how. Also, the result of sim() is already a normal result. What do you mean by normal?
Edit your question with some xexample, code to run, etc and i will help you and upvote you

Comment: @AnderBiguri thank you very much, the normalize is done by  [pn,ps] = mapstd(Input) where the result from neural network will be in same range from -1 to 1, while we have to return it to original range

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question you dont need to go very far. Read the [documentation of mapstd()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/nnet/ref/mapstd.html). In there you have a section called "**Definition**" you have exactly what you are looking for. It is explained why/how to use `mapstd()` and how to reverse the results in a network (ANN in your case) results after simulation. Read that and you'll now how to do it!

For the second question I will reffer to another SO post, where it is explained better than I what I would do, [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971424/continuously-train-matlab-ann-i-e-online-training)! Read that carefully because it is very well explained.

Comment: thank you very much, i read the mapstd() before i post this problem where this function it should have an input with minimum and maximum fir the variable that which should reverse X = mapstd('reverse',Y,PS), where i didnt have for the output from the sim of the network any thing other than that normalize, for the retraining the neural network with adapt i try to read but i didnt understand it, where i already use the train function, how then use this function and how i can tell this function that i already train the network and just need to improve it?

Comment: @Sayed The topic is a bit more complex to explain it in a single post. If you have read the post carefully you will have noticed that 1.- the answerer really recomends NOT to use online learning for NN 2.- if you go to the matlab page linked in the answer you have 3 methods with code on them of how to do it. I really didnt understand you questions. What is your problem?

Comment: @Sayed, and no, you dont need amaximum and minimum. for reverse "unnormalizing" the result you just need to use this code:
anew = mapstd('reverse',a,ps);

Comment: thank you for your feedback, the reverse using mapstd is using the data that want normalize it and the minimum and maximum of it then it can normalize! then to reverse also it need the minimum and maximum of the data from where it cloud come?

Comment: @Sayed For the reverse you need the 3 variables mentioned in my coment:
1.- 'reverse', a string.
2.-a, the result of your sim
3.-ps, obtained by appliying mapstd to the imputs before the NN trainign. Where is the problem, i dont understand. Please, I know english i not your first language, but try to review a bit before posting, I am really not understanding what do you mean, sorry.

Comment: i told you that i know what the mapstd need!! for reverse i need already write reverse and i know that!! and i need the out from the sim string 'a' but the problem is in the ps from we can get it? using the target which used to train the network? ts? see this is what used to train : [pn,ps] = mapstd(in); % pn,tn normalize input and output
[tn,ts] = mapstd(Out); % ts, ps standard diveation and mean

Comment: @Sayed Well if using the ps mapstd gives you doesnt work, I reeally dont know what to use. I am not an expert, sorry.